# What are the implications of spreading stories that are fake solely because they support a opinion?

Tags: truth

I see quite often on many social mediums, the radio, news, as well as advertisements everywhere statements that are untrue or are misleading that support certain opinions. I think it is completely valid to have said opinions and do not want to discuss the implication of any opinion itself. What I want to ponder are the actual implications on a societal and personal level of sharing falsified information to support any thesis. To give an example take the debates on abortion or gun rights. You'd be hard pressed to find many persons who won't willingly ignore the possibility that a story is fake. They will pass it along as fact simply because they agree with it's premise. When told their story is falsified the person usually says their point is still there and that alone justifies it's presence. I can't help but think this has a strong negative affect on a persons critical thinking faculties and exploits a deep weakness to express one's opinions through the empathy in wanting to relate. However it's been going on for as long as I've been around and I haven't been able to pinpoint anything specifically damaging besides a weak moral code / standards for justice.

Comment: I suggest sociologist Jacques Ellul's [Propaganda: The Formation of Men's Attitudes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propaganda:_The_Formation_of_Men's_Attitudes).

Comment: Oh wow thanks! It looks like the fourth chapter goes into detail about my question. I really appreciate it!